# How to pass env variable to rollup.config.js via npm cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

I have a scripts folder in which many individual scripts inside seperate folder, I would like to build each separately via passing the script name as parameter.

I have set up rollup in package.json like `"watch": "rollup --watch --config rollup.config.js"`

I would like to pass parameter from cli like `npm run watch script_name=abc_script`

It can be accessible in rollup.config.js via process.argv

But getting this error

`rollup v1.23.1
bundles abc_script → dist/bundle.js
 [!] Error: Could not resolve entry module`

Everything seems fine without npm cli parameter.

Rollup have --environment variable but it's bit long to use `npm run watch -- --environment script:script_name`

Is there any way to shorten this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass arguments which will be caught by `process.argv` like this

```
npm run watch -- some_arg
```

In your program, you will get an array in process.argv in this the last value will be the value passed to the program.

Comment: Tried but spat out 'Could not resolve entry module (some_arg)'

Answer (score 15):

While the following answer doesn't directly address OP's need (to pass variables in via command line), it does address their desire for brevity ("--environment variable but it's bit long to use")

Create a `.env` file in your project's root directory and fill it with `VAR_NAME=value` on each line

```
NODE_ENV=development
SECRET_KEY=ahuehueheueheueheu
```

**DON'T COMMIT THAT FILE**. Instead, add `.env` to your `.gitignore`.

Next install `dotenv` node package

```
npm i -D dotenv
```

```
yarn add -D dotenv
```

And finally put this at the very top of your `rollup.config.js`

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can pass environment variables to the command - it's much easier to process than command-line arguments.

Cli usage:

`minify=on ./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c`

package.json script:

```
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    ...
    "build-production": "minify=on rollup -c"
  }
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
const enableMinification = process.env.minify === 'on'
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for browser based build? Process is not there in browser resulting `Can't find variable: process`

Comment: This is not for the runtime, it's for the build process, Rollup runs in Node.js regardless of whether you are targeting Node or the browser. If you want  to pass these to the bundle, you will need to use plugin-replace. I.e. in your code you have a literal ENV.MINIFY and the replace plugin will replace it with either true or  false.

Answer (score 2):

`npm run watch -- --environment script=script_name` worked for me, So I can access script_name via process.env in rollup config

Comment: I was able to successfully use this as well.  [Here](https://rollupjs.org/command-line-interface/#environment-values) are the docs.